# How to calculate the total strain-energy for a deformation from a sphere to a cube?

Tags: energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, elasticity, stress-strain

Is there an analytical solution to compute the elastic energy cost to deform an incompressible sphere into a cube ?

Or at least a scaling law ?

Let's assume we would do it with a compressive stress on the surface.

**EDITS AND REMARKS** :

1. If the calculation is possible for a shape close to a cube even now it's not totally a cube it is also welcome !
2. As noticed by Bert Barrois in the comments, the mapping from a ball to a cube is not unique so we have to add a constraint which is the minimization of elastic deformation energy in this transformation if we want the answer to be unique.

I'm not sure that pushing on the ball is the transformation that minimizes the deformation energy. But this was given as an example.

Eventually, I'd welcome any solution for any mapping with an analytical solution or scaling, even if it's not the mapping that minimizes the deformation energy

Comment: How do you imagine this process?

Comment: @AlexTrounev If you pull the surface to 6 orthogonal directions.

Comment: What forces can deform an elastic sphere to turn into a cube? You can try to squeeze with a press. How can we stretch it?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I'd say if you manage to stick some stuff on the surface. But ok I'll change that

Comment: How exact of a cube would you even need?  I feel like this would vary significantly based on what acceptable curvature you allow for the corners.

Comment: That's right. But I'm looking for an analytical solution or for scaling so I didn't want to enter too much into the details of the form. If the question is answered for a shape that is close to a cube it's ok too

Comment: The mapping from a ball to a cube is not unique, unless you impose a further condition, such as minimization of elastic deformation energy.  Extreme deformation would exceed the fracture limit for many materials.

Comment: @BertBarrois I'm adding that to the question

Comment: Maybe using superellipsoid as an analytical basis can help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipsoid

Comment: I know of one mapping from [cube to sphere](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html), and I think that it could be used to compute the energy. Nevertheless, it does not satisfy the incompressibility criterion, i.e., the determinant of the deformation gradient is not 1 for all points. That constraint makes finding the transformation even more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I got a numerical FEM solution in 2D and 3D using the equations of the theory of elasticity, the Dirichlet condition on the surface of a sphere and the condition of conservation of volume. To my surprise, a pretty cube turned out. It should be noted that in a similar solution describing the transformation of a cube into a sphere under the influence of gravitational compression, I could not get the ideal sphere, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130789/whats-the-biggest-cube-you-could-have-before-gravity-rounded-it/505094#505094) .
[image: Figure 1]